# How to correctly run datasette, an uncommonly used python library, on port 80 of a remote server?

Tags: python, database, datasette

I installed [datasette](https://github.com/simonw/datasette), which provides a GUI for accessing SQLite databases, on a remote server and ran the following code in the folder with the SQLite databases.

`nohup datasette serve -h 0.0.0.0 *.db --cors --port 8000 --metadata metadata.json > output.log 2>&1 &`.

When I go to `http://my-remote-server.com:8000`, the site loads. But I know this is not a good long-term solution to running datasette on this server.

What is the "correct" way to have this site run, preferably on server port 80?

Answer (score 1):

Were actually discussing this issue on the Datasette issue tracker at the moment - I would love to put together an official tutorial with suggestions here.

https://github.com/simonw/datasette/issues/514

The short version is that we recommend nginx on port 80 producing to Datasette on port 8000, and using systemd to keep Datasette running.

I've not actually used systemd like this myself yet, but I plan to figure it out soon so I can turn it into documentation.